# What is the ES6 equivalent of Python 'enumerate' for a sequence?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

Python has a [built-in function `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), to get an iterable of `(index, item)` pairs.

Does ES6 have an equivalent for an array? What is it?

```python
def elements_with_index(elements):
    modified_elements = []
    for i, element in enumerate(elements):
         modified_elements.append("%d:%s" % (i, element))
    return modified_elements

print(elements_with_index(["a","b"]))
#['0:a', '1:b']
```

ES6 equivalent without `enumerate`:

```js
function elements_with_index(elements){
     return elements.map(element => elements.indexOf(element) + ':' + element);
 }

console.log(elements_with_index(['a','b']))
//[ '0:a', '1:b' ]
```

Comment: but map or forEach do this already, can get both element and index

Comment: As @juvian says, why not just use the index available in the map? `elements.map(( element, i ) => \`${ i }:${ element }\`);`

Comment: @JamesAllardice with the doc from mozilla :  `elements.map((element,index) => index + ':' + element)`

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Yes there is, check out [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries).

```js
const foobar = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

for (const [index, element] of foobar.entries()) {
  console.log(index, element);
}
```

Comment: This, so simple, so cool. It's closer to the python `enumerate` than `[].map()`, it returns an iterator.

Comment: This is not equivalent to using map((el, idx) => ..), since maybe you want to perform a `filter` but keep the indexes you had before filtering.

Comment: How does this work with types that have `Symbol.iterator` function defined? Python's counterpart `enumerate` accepts any `iterable`.

Answer (score 58):

**Array.prototype.map**

`Array.prototype.map` already gives you the index as the second argument to the callback procedure... And it's [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) almost everywhere.

```
['a','b'].map(function(element, index) { return index + ':' + element; });
//=> ["0:a", "1:b"]
```

I like ES6 too

```
['a','b'].map((e,i) => `${i}:${e}`)
//=> ["0:a", "1:b"]
```

---

**make it lazy**

However, python's `enumerate` is lazy and so we should model that characteristic as well -

```js
function* enumerate (it, start = 0)
{ let i = start
  for (const x of it)
    yield [i++, x]
}

for (const [i, x] of enumerate("abcd"))
  console.log(i, x)
```

```js
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

Specifying the second argument, `start`, allows the caller to control the transform of the index -

```js
for (const [i, x] of enumerate("abcd", 100))
  console.log(i, x)
```

```js
100 a
101 b
102 c
103 d
```

Comment: this is imo better than `entries()`

Comment: @StephenBoesch it depends.. is it possible to `break` the `.map` approach?

Answer (score 28):

```js
let array = [1, 3, 5];
for (let [index, value] of array.entries()) 
     console.log(index + '=' + value);
```

Answer (score 8):

Excuse me if I'm being ignorant (bit of a newbie to JavaScript here), but can't you just use `forEach`? e.g:

```js
function withIndex(elements) {
    var results = [];
    elements.forEach(function(e, ind) {
        results.push(`${e}:${ind}`);
    });
    return results;
}

alert(withIndex(['a', 'b']));
```

There's also [naomik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347308/4077294) answer which is a better fit for this particular use case, but I just wanted to point out that `forEach` also fits the bill.

ES5+ supported.

Answer (score 6):

[`pythonic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pythonic) offers an `enumerate` function that works on all iterables, not just arrays, and returns an [Iterator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pythonic#iterator), like python:

```
import {enumerate} from 'pythonic';

const arr = ['a', 'b'];
for (const [index, value] of enumerate(arr))
    console.log(`index: ${index}, value: ${value}`);
// index: 0, value: a
// index: 1, value: b
```

***Disclosure*** I'm author and maintainer of Pythonic

Comment: Please mention that you help develop `pythonic`. According to [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in Stack Overflow's Help Center, "The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. **However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.**"

Comment: @Keyvan Solomon is completely correct. You own this library, you are the sole author and contributor to it. The way you choose to license it not relevant. You are required to disclose your ownership of or affiliation with any libraries, products, articles, etc which you recommend or link to in your posts. This is a very simple requirement, nobody is being rude to you or asking for anything unreasonable.

Comment: Added per your request

Answer (score 3):

as `Kyle` and `Shanoor` say is [Array.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

but for newbie like me, hard to fully understand its meaning.

so here give an understandable example:

```
for(let curIndexValueList of someArray.entries()){
  console.log("curIndexValueList=", curIndexValueList)
  let curIndex = curIndexValueList[0]
  let curValue = curIndexValueList[1]
  console.log("curIndex=", curIndex, ", curValue=", curValue)
}
```

equivalent to `python` code:

```
for curIndex, curValue in enumerate(someArray):
  print("curIndex=%s, curValue=%s" % (curIndex, curValue))
}
```